# How to change the legend edgecolor and facecolor

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

Is there while `rcParams['legend.frameon'] = 'False'` a simple way to fill the legend area background with a given colour. More specifically I would like the grid not to be seen on the legend area because it disturbs the text reading.

The keyword `framealpha` sounds like what I need but it doesn't change anything.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rcParams['legend.frameon'] = 'False'
plt.plot(range(5), label = u"line")
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc = best)
plt.show()
```

I've also tried:

```
legend = plt.legend(frameon = 1)
frame = legend.get_frame()
frame.set_color('white')
```

but then I need to ask how can I change the background colour while keeping the frame on? Sometimes I want it ON with a background colour other than white. And also, is there a way of changing the colour of the frame? With the above code I was expecting to change the colour of the frame only, not the background.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can set the edge color and the face color separately like this:

```
frame.set_facecolor('green')
frame.set_edgecolor('red')
```

There's more information under FancyBboxPatch [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html).

Answer (score 46):

Using matplotlib.pyplot, `plt.legend(facecolor='white', framealpha=1)` will give your legend a white background without transparency.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to **Molly**'s method you can turn the frame off using the linewidth:

```
frame.set_linewidth(0)
```

I used that method in a small convenience function I wrote to hide the legend frames for the same reason you cite.  The function is called `adjust_legends` in the `print_targeted_plots` module available [from github](https://github.com/AndrewDDavis/Python-print_targeted_plots).