# How to create a basic legend to a multicolored line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, legend

I am currently finishing a bigger project and the last part is to add a simple legend to a plot of a multicolored line. The line only contains two different colors.

The following image shows the plot when created.[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VYehsd6ByqdpZcS0u7Uh7OjklNqMgs_H]

The next image shows the same plot with higher resolution.[image]

The plot displays the distance between Earth and Mars over time. For the months March to August the line is orange, for the other months it's blue. The legend should come in a simple box in the upper right corner of the plot showing a label each for the used colors. Something like [this](https://matplotlib.org/_images/sphx_glr_usage_003.png) would be nice.

The data for the plot comes from a huge matrix I named `master_array`. It contains a lot more information that is necessary for some tasks prior to show the plot this question is regarding to.
Important for the plot I am struggling with are the columns 0, 1 and 6 which are containing the date, distance between the planets at related date and in column 6 I set a flag to determine whether the given point belongs to the 'March to August' set or not (`0` is for Sep-Feb / "winter", `1` is for Mar-Aug / "summer"). The `master_array` is a numpy array, dtype is `float64`. It contains approximately 45k data points.

It looks like:

```py
In [3]: master_array
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1.89301010e+07,  1.23451036e+00, -8.10000000e+00, ...,
         1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.89300000e+03],
       [ 1.89301020e+07,  1.24314818e+00, -8.50000000e+00, ...,
         2.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.89300000e+03],
       [ 1.89301030e+07,  1.25179997e+00, -9.70000000e+00, ...,
         3.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.89300000e+03],
       ...,
       [ 2.01903100e+07,  1.84236878e+00,  7.90000000e+00, ...,
         1.00000000e+01,  3.00000000e+00,  2.01900000e+03],
       [ 2.01903110e+07,  1.85066892e+00,  5.50000000e+00, ...,
         1.10000000e+01,  3.00000000e+00,  2.01900000e+03],
       [ 2.01903120e+07,  1.85894904e+00,  9.40000000e+00, ...,
         1.20000000e+01,  3.00000000e+00,  2.01900000e+03]])
```

This is the function to get the plot I described in the beginning:

```py
def md_plot3(dt64=np.array, md=np.array, swFilter=np.array):
    """ noch nicht fertig """
    y, m, d = dt64.astype(int) // np.c_[[10000, 100, 1]] % np.c_[[10000, 100, 100]]
    dt64 = y.astype('U4').astype('M8') + (m-1).astype('m8[M]') + (d-1).astype('m8[D]')

    cmap = ListedColormap(['b','darkorange'])

    plt.figure('zeitlich-global betrachtet')
    plt.title("Marsdistanz unter Berücksichtigung der Halbjahre der steigenden und sinkenden Temperaturen",
              loc='left', wrap=True)
    plt.xlabel("Zeit in Jahren\n")
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
    plt.ylabel("Marsdistanz in AE\n(1 AE = 149.597.870,7 km)")
#    plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=True) # worked formerly
    ax=plt.gca()
    plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

#convert dates to numbers first
    inxval = mdates.date2num(dt64)
    points = np.array([inxval, md]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)

    lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, linewidth=3)
# set color to s/w values
    lc.set_array(swFilter)
    ax.add_collection(lc)

    loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))

    ax.autoscale_view()
```

In the bigger script there is also another function (scatter plot) to mark the minima and maxima of the curve, but I guess this is not so important here.

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223702/adding-a-legend-to-a-matplotlib-plot-with-a-multicolored-line) resulting in a legend, that shows a vertical colorbar and only one label and also both options described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877666/add-legends-to-linecollection-plot) because it looks more like what I am aiming for but couldn't make it work for my case.

Maybe I should add that I am only a beginner in python, this is my first project so I am not familiar with the deeper functionality of `matplotlib` what is probably the reason why I am not able to customize the mentioned answers to get it to work in my case.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the help of the user ImportanceOfBeingErnest I made some improvements:
[image: "improvements"]

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

def md_plot4(dt64=np.array, md=np.array, swFilter=np.array):
    y, m, d = dt64.astype(int) // np.c_[[10000, 100, 1]] % np.c_[[10000, 100, 100]]
    dt64 = y.astype('U4').astype('M8') + (m-1).astype('m8[M]') + (d-1).astype('m8[D]')

    z = np.unique(swFilter)

    cmap = ListedColormap(['b','darkorange'])

    fig = plt.figure('Test')
    plt.title("Test", loc='left', wrap=True)
    plt.xlabel("Zeit in Jahren\n")
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
    plt.ylabel("Marsdistanz in AE\n(1 AE = 149.597.870,7 km)")
#    plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=True) # worked formerly
    ax=plt.gca()
    plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
    #plt.style.use('classic')

#convert dates to numbers first
    inxval = mdates.date2num(dt64)
    points = np.array([inxval, md]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)

    lc = LineCollection(segments, array=z, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap), 
                        linewidth=3)
# set color to s/w values
    lc.set_array(swFilter)
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    fig.colorbar(lc)


    loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))

    ax.autoscale_view()

    def make_proxy(zvalue, scalar_mappable, **kwargs):
        color = scalar_mappable.cmap(scalar_mappable.norm(zvalue))
        return Line2D([0, 1], [0, 1], color=color, **kwargs)
    proxies = [make_proxy(item, lc, linewidth=2) for item in z]
    ax.legend(proxies, ['Winter', 'Summer'])


    plt.show()

md_plot4(dt64, md, swFilter)
```

+What is good about it:

Well it shows a legend and it shows the right colors according to the labels.

-What is still to optimize:

1) The legend is not in a box and the 'lines' of the legend are interfering with the bottom layers of the plot. As the user ImportanceOfBeingErnest stated out this is caused by using `plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')`. So if there's a way to use `plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')` together with the legend style of `plt.style.use('classic')` that might would help. 
2) The bigger issue is the colorbar. I added the `fig.colorbar(lc)` line to the original code to achieve what I was looking for according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877666/add-legends-to-linecollection-plot/19881647#19881647).

So I tried some other changes:

I used the `plt.style.use('classic')` to get a legend in the way I need it but this costs me the nice style of `plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')` as mentioned before. Moreover I disabled the `colorbar` line I added prior according to the mentioned [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877666/add-legends-to-linecollection-plot/19881647#19881647).

This is what I got:

[image: more "improvement"]

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

def md_plot4(dt64=np.array, md=np.array, swFilter=np.array):
    y, m, d = dt64.astype(int) // np.c_[[10000, 100, 1]] % np.c_[[10000, 100, 100]]
    dt64 = y.astype('U4').astype('M8') + (m-1).astype('m8[M]') + (d-1).astype('m8[D]')

    z = np.unique(swFilter)

    cmap = ListedColormap(['b','darkorange'])

    #fig =
    plt.figure('Test')
    plt.title("Test", loc='left', wrap=True)
    plt.xlabel("Zeit in Jahren\n")
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
    plt.ylabel("Marsdistanz in AE\n(1 AE = 149.597.870,7 km)")
#    plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=True) # worked formerly
    ax=plt.gca()
    #plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
    plt.style.use('classic')

#convert dates to numbers first
    inxval = mdates.date2num(dt64)
    points = np.array([inxval, md]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)

    lc = LineCollection(segments, array=z, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap), 
                        linewidth=3)
# set color to s/w values
    lc.set_array(swFilter)
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    #fig.colorbar(lc)


    loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))

    ax.autoscale_view()

    def make_proxy(zvalue, scalar_mappable, **kwargs):
        color = scalar_mappable.cmap(scalar_mappable.norm(zvalue))
        return Line2D([0, 1], [0, 1], color=color, **kwargs)
    proxies = [make_proxy(item, lc, linewidth=2) for item in z]
    ax.legend(proxies, ['Winter', 'Summer'])


    plt.show()

md_plot4(dt64, md, swFilter)
```

+What is good about it:

It shows the legend in the way I need it.

It doesn't show a colorbar anymore.

-What is to optimize:

The plot isn't multicolored anymore.

Neither is the legend.

The `classic` style is not what I was looking for as I explained before...

---

So if anyone has a good advice please let me know!

I am using numpy version 1.16.2 and matplotlib version 3.0.3

Comment: does LineCollection.set_label() help you at all?  Mind you will have to call ax.legend() afterwards

Comment: Can you be a little more precisely? When I added those two lines (including an argument) I get `TypeError: set_label() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'`

Comment: well, set_label is the function call to set the label, so you have to give it the label you want in the legend as a string.   `lc.set_label('a label for the legend')`.  `ax.legend()` will then generate the legend based on what the lines look like and their labels.  I have never worked with LineCollections though so i don't know what will happen.

Comment: Exactly what I did and what resulted in mentioned error message...

Comment: can you copy and paste the code, just as a sanity check?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/V1DRVqDJ

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19881647/4124317) is **precisely** what you want. Note that it's close to impossible to help if you just say "didn't work". Show the attempt, make it reproducible!

Comment: okay, so in that code you called LineCollection.set_label, and I know that's what I said, but LineCollection is the class, whereas you need to call it on your instance `lc.set_label('label 1')`

Comment: @VinceW. Okay, changed it but it only results in one single label where I need a label for every color used in the multicolored line.

Comment: It seems like the comment from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is what you want then, no?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest here is what I tried: https://pastebin.com/nH41AhSr
The error message `NameError: name 'color' is not defined` is obvious yet I don't know what changes I have to make.

Comment: Line 43 needs to be indented. Also `z` needs to be a list of the values to map, in your case `[0,1]`. Finally, since you have two values, you need two labels, not 4.

Comment: Nice! How do I get rid of the colorbar? And is it possible to have the legend in a box?

Comment: Well, guess what happens if you remove the line `fig.colorbar` from your code?!

Comment: Legends come in boxes automatically. You changed that by using "seaborn-whitegrid" or so.

Comment: If I remove `fig.colorbar(lc)` from the code it results in an all blue line https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yV4SD479vXpSDxM_S31X04-MlU6VmXK0

Also there is no box for the legend when I remove the line with "seaborn-whitegrid".

Comment: he style hasn't changed; so probably you run some interactive session which you need to close. As to why the colorbar removal removes your colors, I have no idea. It does the same in the original post, but not in any of my answers; will need to check the difference.

Comment: Ok, there is a [funny bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13887).  I updated the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19881647/4124317) to work, even if you remove the colorbar.

Comment: Concerning the legend, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729473/seaborn-legend-with-background-color). Don't use `"classic"` that is meant for backwards compatibility. The default style is called `"default"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer how to create a basic legend to a multicolored line, containing multiple labels for each used color and without showing a colorbar next to the plot (standard colorbar, nothing inside the legend; see update of original question for more information about the issues):

Thanks to a lot of helpful comments I figured out to add a norm to the `LineCollection()` to avoid ending up with a monocolored line when removing the colorbar by disabling `fig.colorbar()`  (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19881647/revisions))
The additional argument (in this case "norm") to add was `norm=plt.Normalize(z.min(), z.max())`, where `z` is the array that contains the information responsible for the different colors of the segments. Note that `z` only needs to hold one single element for each different color. This is why I wrapped my `swFilter` array, consisting of one flag per data point, into `np.unique()`.

To get a proper legend inside a box not touching the `plt.style.use()`, I simply had to add the right arguments to `ax.legend()`. In my case a simple `frameon=True` did the job.

The result is the following:
[image: plot of multicolored line showing no colorbar but a boxed legend]

Here is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

def md_plot4(dt64=np.array, md=np.array, swFilter=np.array):
    y, m, d = dt64.astype(int) // np.c_[[10000, 100, 1]] % np.c_[[10000, 100, 100]]
    dt64 = y.astype('U4').astype('M8') + (m-1).astype('m8[M]') + (d-1).astype('m8[D]')

    z = np.unique(swFilter)

    cmap = ListedColormap(['b','darkorange'])

    #fig =
    plt.figure('Test')
    plt.title("Marsdistanz unter Berücksichtigung der Halbjahre der steigenden und sinkenden Temperaturen\n",
              loc='left', wrap=True)
    plt.xlabel("Zeit in Jahren\n")
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
    plt.ylabel("Marsdistanz in AE\n(1 AE = 149.597.870,7 km)")
    plt.tight_layout()
    ax=plt.gca()
    plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

#convert dates to numbers first
    inxval = mdates.date2num(dt64)
    points = np.array([inxval, md]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)

    lc = LineCollection(segments, array=z, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap),
                        linewidth=3, norm=plt.Normalize(z.min(), z.max()))
# set color to s/w values
    lc.set_array(swFilter)
    ax.add_collection(lc)

    loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))

    ax.autoscale_view()

    def make_proxy(zvalue, scalar_mappable, **kwargs):
        color = scalar_mappable.cmap(scalar_mappable.norm(zvalue))
        return Line2D([0, 1], [0, 1], color=color, **kwargs)
    proxies = [make_proxy(item, lc, linewidth=2) for item in z]
    ax.legend(proxies, ['Halbjahr der sinkenden \nTemperaturen',
                        'Halbjahr der steigenden \nTemperaturen'], frameon=True)

    plt.show()

md_plot4(dt64, md, swFilter)
```

---

Note that I added `plt.tight_layout()` to ensure the title of the plot and the description of the axes are shown without any cut-offs in the window mode.

**New issue** now (resulting from adding `tight_layout()`) is that the plot gets horizontal compressed, even though there is much space available on the right side of the plot (the place where a colorbar would appear when called).

This requires another fix but currently I don't know how. So if anyone knows how to prevent the plots title and description of the axes from getting cut-off in window mode, I would be very grateful if you leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To get a multicoloured plot in matplotlib, label your plots and then call the [`legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) function. The following sample code is taken from a [link](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-legend/), but as links break, here's the post..

The chart used here is a line, but the same principle applies to other chart types, as you can see from this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125722/adding-a-legend-to-pyplot-in-matplotlib-in-the-most-simple-manner-possible)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
y2 = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
x = np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, label='$y = numbers')
ax.plot(x, y2, label='$y2 = other numbers')
plt.title('Legend inside')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

This code will show the following image (with the legend inside the chart)

[image: legend]

Hope this helps